# Para que serve <! [CDATA []]> em XML?

Tags: xml

Em alguns exemplos de plataformas, tem entre as *tags* o `<![CDATA []]>`, mas afinal para que serve isso no XML?

Modelo de um XML a ser seguido de uma plataforma.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<loja>
   <produto>
      <link><![CDATA[http://www.loja.com.br/blusas/blusa-feminina?idparceiro=P1]]></link>
      <imagem><![CDATA[http://www.loja.com.br/imagens/blusa-feminina-1.jpg]]></imagem>
      <nome><![CDATA[Blusa feminina vermelha]]></nome>
      <categoria><![CDATA[Blusas Femininas]]></categoria>
      <descricao><![CDATA[Blusa feminina com gola em V e detalhes em strass.]]></descricao>
      <valor><![CDATA[119,00]]></valor>
      <valor_promo><![CDATA[95,90]]></valor_promo>
      <parcelamento><![CDATA[2x R$47,95]]></parcelamento>
      <cor><![CDATA[Vermelho, Azul, Branco]]></cor>
      <marca><![CDATA[Tommy Hilfiger]]></marca>
      <modelo><![CDATA[Único]]></modelo>
      <material><![CDATA[100% algodão]]></material>
      <tamanho><![CDATA[P, M, G]]></tamanho>
      <sexo><![CDATA[Feminino]]></sexo>
   </produto>
</loja>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

O [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect) serve para indicar que o texto dentro da área dele é um texto comum e não pode ser interpretado como parte da marcação do XML.

Isto é útil quando uma parte do texto de um determinado elemento pode ser confundido com partes da marcação do XML, o que não é o caso do exemplo mostrado. É uma forma de escapar os caracteres.

Deve ter um motivo específico da plataforma para usar indiscriminadamente. Talvez por falha da especificação deles. Talvez porque eles não têm controle sobre o conteúdo e pode haver caracteres conflitantes (pode conter HTML). Talvez por algum motivo que só eles podem explicar (provavelmente via documentação). O que é certo é que deve ser seguido se eles mandam.

Um exemplo de boa utilização seria:

```
<secao><![CDATA[<sexo>Feminino</sexo>]]><secao>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Cdata.xml).

O que parece ser uma *tag* do XML é apenas um texto comum que por acaso se parece com, e provavelmente representa um outro XML.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA).

Comment: Entendo que, uma vez que o trecho CDATA pode aparecer em qualquer parte do XML em que possa ir texto, como por exemplo entre duas tags, acredito que a orientação geral seja buscar na biblioeca de _XML parsing_ que estiver usando se existe o recurso pronto de escapar esse conteúdo CDATA no texto trazido para um determinado componente da árvore XML..