# Para que serve e qual a diferença de usar <![CDATA[]]> dentro de uma tag <script>?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xhtml

Pra que serve, ou qual a diferença de usar ou não o conteúdo do script com esse CDATA?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA  

   ...

//]]
</script>
```

Comment: Não precisa se desculpar, você não é idiota por não saber algo.

Comment: Relacionado: [Para que serve CDATA em XML?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81536/4808).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Às vezes, dentro da sintaxe XML, os desenvolvedores irão colocar uma sequência de entradas entre os dados de caracteres, ou suportes `CDATA`. A informação que é colocada entre estes suportes é irreconhecível para o analisador XML. A motivação para a utilização do `CDATA`, é para colocar notas especiais dentro do código ou incluir caracteres ilegais, como comercial ou "<>" que normalmente causam o XML parser crash (acidente no analisador de XML). Se tais símbolos são essenciais para a entrada, então a aplicação do `CDATA` é uma obrigação.

Comment: faz sentido, pq algumas vezes o javascript não funcionou sem CDATA

Answer (score 6):

Do ponto de vista do Javascript, esse CDATA não faz nada pois ele está dentro de um comentário. Ele está lá como uma HTML virar um documento XML válido além de ser simplesmente um documento HTML.

Por exemplo o seguinte script não é XML válido pois a tag "`</blah>`" não está balanceada. (Lembre-se que do ponto de vista do XML, o "`//`" não é um  comentário).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //</blah>
</script>
```

Dito isso, na prática esse CDATA não serve pra nada já que HTML não é e nem precisa ser XML. Por exemplo, em HTML `<x/>` não é equivalente a `<x></x>`. Na verdade. `<x/>` equivale a `<x>`, com a `/` sendo simplesmente ignorada.

Além disso, não precisa por o `type="text/javascript"`. A ideia original desse atributo era permitir linguagens de scripting diferentes mas isso também é outra coisa que não vingou.

```
<script>
  //...
</script>
```

Comment: obrigado, acho q seu comentário mais o do @durtto esclarece pq ele as vezes se faz necessário.

Comment: Só para clarificar: Hoje em dia tem 99% de chance de não ser necessário. Só vai fazer diferença se seu sistema estiver usando ferramentas de XML para manipular o seu HTML. Do ponto de vista do browser o CDATA é totalmente desnecessário.

Comment: @hugomg vingou sim, já ouviu falar do CoffeeScript? `<script type="text/coffeescript"></script>`

Comment: Na verdade, qualquer "type=" diferente de "text/javascript" é completamente ignorado pelo browser. No seu caso tem um script javascript que percorre todas essas tags marcadas com o text/cofeescript e roda o interpretador cofeescript no conteúdo delas.