# A seção de configuração não pode conter um elemento de texto ou CDATA

Tags: c#, app.config, configurationmanager

O erro começou a aparecer quando adicionei a variavel:

```
 <add key="Teste" value="true"/>
```

App.Config inteira:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>﻿
   <add key="Teste" value="true"/>
     </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="x86"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

C#:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Teste"]))
```

Alguém sabe oque pode ser? Valeu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz alguns testes aqui e na sua seção `appSettings` está vindo com um espaço em branco e isso está causando o erro, pois há um elemento de texto na seção, o espaço em branco. veja na imagem a baixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após remover esse espaço o erro parou de acontecer

Veja mais sobre CDATA aqui: [Para que serve <! [CDATA []]> em XML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81536/para-que-serve-cdata-em-xml)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]