# Código desconhecido na página HTML

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web

Estou fazendo um projeto básico pra por em prática o aprendizado.

Estou com um problema muito estranho, que é esse código aparecendo ao lado do meu conteúdo, na página do navegador.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele aparece sempre que seto o display como flex no seletor `* { }` do CSS. Não sei dizer ao certo, mas parece que tem a ver com o `live server`, a extensão do VScode.

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Tag link que é utilizada para incorporar o arquivo css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script async src="./index.js" ></script> 
    <title>IMC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <header id="cabelçalho" >
        <h1>Calculadora - IMC</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="corpo">
        <div>
            <p>Nome:</p>
            <input id="nome" type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Altura</p>
            <input id="altura" type="number">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Peso</p>
            <input id="peso" type="number">
        </div>
        <button id="botão">Calcular</button>
    </main>
    <!-- <footer id="resultado">
        <textarea name="resposta" id="resposta" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </footer> -->
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* "Zerando" o HTML */
*{
    margin: 0;
    /* box-sizing eh utilizado para usar o box model */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
       */
       display: flex;
}
.container{
    
    flex-direction: column;
    
    /* Dexia a altura do container centralizada independente do dispositivo */
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center ;
    background: tomato;
}
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Para que serve <! \[CDATA \[\]\]> em XML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81536/para-que-serve-cdata-em-xml)

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiquei o problema.

Você está usando Display flex no *.

Dessa forma vc está alterando o estado de display de toda a janela, não apenas do que está dentro do seu body.
Assim todo o documento se tornou flexivel, ficando do tamanho do seu conteúdo e subscrevendo qualquer outro parametro display que existia, ex: display none.

Esse texto que você está vendo é de fato do live server, mas ele não aparece em tela, pois fica oculto com display none.
Quando vc alterou para display flex tornou esse conteúdo visivel.

Solução: use display flex diretamente nos campos onde deseja que o tamanho seja flexivel, fica muito dificil manipular os tamanhos e posições quando um documento tem um nivel muito alto no display flex.

Nesse caso use o display flex no body{} e vá testando, se caso não ficar bom desca uma propriedade abaixo até ficar bom .

espero ter ajudado,.

Comment: Ajudou de mais.  Agradeço pela resposta!

Comment: Disponha cara precisando de ajuda. Manda aqui no Stack que a galera sempre dá uma força. 

Fortalece ai colocando uma setinha pra cima na resposta, que ai a resposta vai servir para ajudar mais pessoas que pegarem o mesmo erro